# How to delete firestore security rules history

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

so we stumbled over the issue that we hit the quota limit for stored firestore security rules of 2500. During deployment the CLI asks us if we want to delete the oldest 10 rules. Since we want to automate our deployment reacting to a console prompt is not exactly what we want.

Anyone knows how to mass delete the complete firestore security rule history without having to do it manually one by one trough firebase?

I couldn't find any info on that whatsoever from Googles side...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you can delete all security rules at once, but as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#manage_rulesets), you can avoid manual work by creating a logic to delete the oldest rules:

> For example, to delete ALL rule sets deployed for longer than 30 days:
>
> ```
> const thirtyDays = new Date(Date.now() - THIRTY_DAYS_IN_MILLIS);
> const promises = [];
> allRulesets.forEach((rs) => {
>   if (new Date(rs.crateTime) < thirtyDays) {
>     promises.push(admin.securityRules().deleteRuleset(rs.name));
>   }
> });
> await Promise.all(promises);
> console.log(`Deleted ${promises.length} rulesets.`);
> ```

Comment: Thanks that will help me, not sure who wrote this part of the documentation but it's full of errors. Hard to understand how "crateTime" and admin.securityRules().listRulesetMetadata(pageToken: pageToken);
got past any dev...

Comment: So this seems to return more than just firestore rules, I get rule entries with dates that have no entry in my firestore history and there doesn't seem to be a way to filter those.

Comment: @user3399276 glad you found this answer helpful. I would create a new thread regarding filtering rule entries

Comment: the docs of this are total crap... pageToken: pageToken no type for it.